# How to keep per-keyboard layout settings?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, xkb

I am using `xmodmap` (and sometimes `xkbcomp` instead) to adjust my keyboard layout (e.g. mapping Caps Lock to the Mod3 modifier).

When I plug a USB keyboard into my laptop or insert a [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/yubikey/) (which acts like a keyboard), the settings for my laptop keyboard are immediately lost, leaving me in situations where Mod3 stops working and I cannot use my window manager any more.

How can I make my `xmodmap`/`xkbcomp` settings **persistent** or at least **persistent per X session** for my internal keyboard, so that it keeps the layout, no matter if I attach other keybaords?

Answer (score 2):

You may try [inputplug](http://bitbucket.org/andrew_shadura/inputplug), a daemon which connects to your X server and listens for XInput events. It can run your script which reloads the keymap:

```
inputplug -c ~/.xkb_load_hook
```

And `~/.xkb_load_hook` in my case is:

```
#!/bin/sh

xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb_keymap :0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
xmodmap ~/.xmodmaprc

sun_id=$(xinput list | grep "HID 0430:0005" | grep -o 'id=[0-9]*' | cut -d = -f 2)

if [ -n "$sun_id" ]
then
    xkbcomp -i "$sun_id" -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb_keymap_sun :0 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
fi
```

The last bit detects a Sun Type 6 keyboard and applies different settings for it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not X, but `gnome-settings-daemon` that resets my layouts when I attach a new keyboard.

This helped: [udev rule to auto load keyboard layout when usb keyboard plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/249064/udev-rule-to-auto-load-keyboard-layout-when-usb-keyboard-plugged-in#comment789742_249150)

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/keyboard/active false
```

to disable it from doing that.